Open the camera with TextureView and the last preview image will be displayed when onrestart activity
Open the camera with TextureView and press the home button. When I re-open the app, TextureView still displays the last preview image. I  try to Cover preview_frame_root with another View when onstop. Restarting APP will still display the camera preview Image before TextureView
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false">
</FrameLayout>

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

I add View to cover preview_root and hide the view when onrestart (I add some time delay);
But still not work also will show amoment last camera preview imange on TextureView
I think some caching is causing the problem here.
I set used the code onstop or onrestart method :
View cover = findViewById(cover);
cover.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK):
cover.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

Cover view will show but also have some delay, so I also look preview_root view. it look like that UI is not update in time
